# Programmatically setting layout constraints in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I have a Collection View Cell in which I'm trying to layout three labels and an image.  I seem to have the vertical layout working ok, but I just can't seem to get the horizontal layout to an acceptable state -- the labels just don't seem to want to work as I'd like.

Basically, the vertical dimension is fixed, but I have the horizontal size of the cell changing based on how wide the screen is, but typically around 320.  I want the image to be in a fixed position, but the UILabels to then take up any remaining space to the right of the image.

I have included a picture below of my expected layout:

[image]

For the vertical layout I have the following, where the labels are l1 to l3 and the image is i1:

To constrain the image 20px from the top:

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[i1(42)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
```

To constrain the labels vertically in the fixed 134 height cell:

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[l1(21)][l2(21)]-10-[l3(42)]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
```

I was then expecting the labels horizontally to be as follows:

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[i1(42)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-82-[l1]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-82-[l2]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-82-[l3]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
```

Which almost works.  I have had to set the following to get the multiline label to behave too:

```
descriptionLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(0, forAxis: .Horizontal)
```

The issue I'm having though is that the labels all still appear to be too far to the left and it is leaving quite a gap on the right, as if the width isn't dynamically adjusting?

Any thoughts on how I can correct that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you set the constraints in Interface builder as it can automatically detect ambiguous constraints. It's very hard to tell in such cases. Or create the cell in a nib and load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought here... have you tried setting the left side of the label to the right side of the image?

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[i1]-20-[l1]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[i1]-20-[l2]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[i1]-20-[l3]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dictionaryOfViews))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Yes, I should have mentioned I tried that... I get the same result though unfortunately, just a little too much space to the right... Almost as if it has the size of the cell wrong...